# CSS - Como cambio el tamaño de mi imagen de fondo?

Tags: css, scss

como cambio el tamaño de imagen de fondo? por ejemplo quiero cambiar mi imagen "flower" en el fondo "paper"

```
#example1 {
background: url(images/flower.webp) no-repeat right, url(images/paper.jpg) left top repeat;}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `background-size` para determinar el ancho y el alto de la imagen de fondo:

```
background-size: 300px 300px;
```